# What type of function can be secure & easy password on webSite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Sorry in advance for my poor English & this question might be off-topic.

I would like to know the best function for countermeasure of password cracking.

Setting each Password in each web service is not easy way.
Same Password in each web service is not safe way.

So I wonder  just memorizing the function and  calculating password each time in each site is good way.

Specifically, we will deal with this method like this.

1. Input value are  a name of web service & count of its name.For Unity, we adopt the name from domain.

   Example web service: https://google.com

   Input value x:   google (String Type) 
   Input value y:   6   (count Number of domain name,Number Type)

or x should change some yourmasterword+domainname,as mr.orion suggested.

2. function is something like this.(this is just a example)

$$   f(x,y)= (x−２)/2 +4y$$

3. The rule of four arithmetic operations of x(string value)  is as follows.

   addition:(x+x) →　googlegoogle  (x+y)→google6 (x+2)→　emmejc
   subtraction:(x-x)→none or 0  (x-y)→6google (x-2)→iqqing
   multiplication:(x × x)→googlegoogle (x × y)→google6 (x × 2)→　google2
   division:(x÷x)→1 (x÷y)→1 (x÷2)→goog 
   ✴︎Addition or Subtraction of stringType with number is to aim for 　distributing of letter.This action proceed to the front(add) and back(sub) in alphabetical order.

4.So you just remember the function and when you go to website you calculate.

$$   f(x,y)= (x−２)/2 +4y$$
[google → (iqqing)/2 +24= iggi24]
[Apple →　(ynnng)/2 + 20 = ynn20]
[Netflix → (lgrdjgv)/2+28 = lgrdj28]

Infact ,these webSite require 8~20 characters. So function must contain String-type multiplication.

Again I want to know the function type that easy to calculate, easy to memory, return high-entropy values.
Is that algebraic equation?

(I know the existence of password management soft.But I think increasing options is good.)

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two types of security. In one, the algorithm is known, and the security comes from how difficult it is to invert the function (guess the key, undo encryption, etc). This is how all computerized security works (public-private key security, symmetric key encryption, hashing algorithms for storing passwords) because the algorithm has to be known by all parties involved in order to communicate. Protection is provided by computational difficulty.

The other way is that the *algorithm* is secret. This can be used in communication between pre-arranged groups of people. In that case, it's quite more difficult to figure out, and harder to reverse-engineer.

What you want here is a way to *generate* a password for yourself! There are two points of weakness. First is that nobody should know you are using this way of inventing passwords. Second is, that the produced password (no matter how you got it) has to be hard to guess (strong password). So **google2** is a bad password, no matter if you got it from your algorithm or just made it up. It can be cracked by a dictionary attack or even just guessing (only 7 digits).

Don't make your algorithm too complicated... use "salt". When passwords are stored properly, your password is combined with a random "salt" string before it is put into a hashing function. You should do the same. The function can then be very simple or even trivial. Invent a "master" password that is long and easy to remember. Then just add suffixes/prefixes/modifications. This way, as long as your master password is strong and noone know it, you are safe.

For example, my main password can be "b1ueH0RSE955!" and then on google, I can use "b1ueH0RSE955!_google", where I can make it more secure by appending something that is calculated from all of it (hash-like process, for example, just "adding" all the numbers and letter positions together modulo 26 and converting it back to a letter, possibly ignoring other characters).

The main point is: output password has to be secure, and input password has to be secret. Then, even if you tell people how you "compute" a password (which is still not a good idea, by the way), they have to guess the main part of the password, otherwise they know nothing. Making your algorithm unnecessarily complicated doesn't help, and might make things worse (false sense of security). The entropy is generated by a sufficiently good salt string / master password, and if that is strong and well protected, the rest doesn't matter much.

Comment: Thank you for nice tip,orion.Input should  be secret,that can be a weak point.And this way looks complicated.But making function by themselves with individual taste can not be weak way. Sorry for my poor english. each person make each function is the key point of this way.

Comment: Yes, you can use any function you want, but it *must* produce long enough and complicated passwords, otherwise they can be guessed directly without knowing your function.

Comment: "must produce long enough and complicated passwords"yes ,you are right.so i want to know about  the way.that rule of four arithmetic is just example. I hope that somebody smart may hit upon more good way on this idea.

Comment: you say that the way of "salt" is more secure than making function.Is that right? I thought presuming 
any‐degree equation is difficult.

Comment: You need both. So your function combines salt with other inputs to make password. I showed just adding a string, but you can combine in other ways. For example, you could have f(salt,website)=salt+website.

Comment: Thanks,onion! I get it.I add its info in question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for hashing algorithms, like [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). For example, the MD5 of `google` is `C822C1B63853ED273B89687AC505F9FA`. You can try it [here](https://passwordsgenerator.net/md5-hash-generator/).

Comment: Thank you for quick reply,jack.But not MD5.Because that need another Generator or Calculator like this. I just want more simple way.it means password control way that  needs  only self-brain.